# Reference element used an if statement using "this"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I'm open to the idea that this is a bad concept as I haven't been able to find any examples of it but I could be using the wrong search terms.  Anyways,  I have this `View` that dynamically creates a list of `checkboxes` and accompanying text and the goal is to have each `checkbox` whose `value` matches the `value` of a `hiddentextbox` to be `checked` automatically for the user.  However, I am not sure how to accomplish this.  My current idea was to have an `if-statement` compare the `values` and then `check` the appropriate `boxes` using `this` to reference the particular `checkbox` in question since there can be an unknown number of them created, however this doesn't work.  Code below.

Relevant JQuery Code:

```
if ($('.skill-checkbox').val() == $('#HiddenAccessPoint').val()) {
$(this).attr('checked', true);
}
```

Relevant View Code:

```
<input class="skill-checkbox" name="<%= log.DateEntered%>" type="checkbox" value="  <%= log.EntryAccessPoint%>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="HiddenAccessPoint" id="HiddenAccessPoint" value="<%= HttpContext.Current.Session["AccessPoint"].ToString()%>" />
```

Note: Jquery version is 1.4.4

Comment: There is no `this` inside an if statement unless it's defined outside the if statement. Your "jQuery" code doesn't and can't do what you expect it to. You'll have to use an each loop and compare each element one by one, or use an attribute equals selector.

Comment: Are the checkboxes coming from your Model?  I assume you also have the value of hiddentextbox available in your Controller.  Why not just set the value on the Model?

Comment: Alright, that's what I wasn't sure of.  I was looking for an explanation elsewhere about using `this` for an if statement but I guess that's why there wasn't one.

Comment: @cadrell0 The checkboxes are coming from the View.  They are dynamically generated based on the number of results that come to my Model which has an IEnumerable listing for the results that come from the DB.  This just seemed to be a simpler way for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.skill-checkbox').each(function(){

  if ($(this).val() == $('#HiddenAccessPoint').val()) {
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
  } 
});
```

Try the above.

"this" is not referring to the checkbox inside the if, so that's why it's not working

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine from what I just tested.  I see that now thanks to you and @Kevin B.  Like I said, I wasn't sure if it would as I hadn't found any explanations about trying to use that.